# bootstrap CSS chat-bubble has content leaking outside the div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a CSS chat-bubble and I used bootstraps `container-fluid` class to wrap the content in the div. The div's content does not spill in width, but in height when there is too much content the words leak outside of the div. I want to make it so that that div will automatically expand in height to cater to the contents of the div. I am taking UI into consideration here so I can't use scroll properties. Any ideas? Thanks!

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}

.bubble {


position: relative;
width: 275px;
height: 125px;
padding: 1px;
background: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
border: #7F7F7F solid 1px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 14px 23px 14px 0;
border-color:transparent #FFFFFF;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
left: -23px;
top: 49px;
}

.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 14px 23px 14px 0;
border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
left: -24px;
top: 49px;
}

.oddbubble 
{
float:right;
position: relative;
width: 275px;
height: 125px;
padding: 1px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
border: #7F7F7F solid 1px;
}

.oddbubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 14px 0 14px 23px;
border-color: transparent #FFFFFF;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: -23px;
top: 49px;
}

.oddbubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 14px 0 14px 23px;
border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
right: -24px;
top: 49px;
}

.container-fluid {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bubble.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="bubble">
     <p>this text spills outside my chat bubble.this text spills outside my chat bubble.this text spills outside my chat bubble</p>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
   
  <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="oddbubble">
     <p>this text spills outside my chat bubble.this text spills outside my chat bubble.this text spills outside my chat bubble</p>
     <p>this text spills outside my chat bubble.this text spills outside my chat bubble.this text spills outside my chat bubble</p>
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
   
 </div> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please do not use [bootstrap] as tag, that's another thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from `.bubble` :

```
height: 125px;
```

Edit: Fix for the triangles use dynamic location based on parent height.:

```
top: 40%;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized the triangle I created gets misplaced based on content. Any ideas how I can go about that?